# How to join results from multiple sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I wannt to display the required columns that is defines in SELECT, once the one condition is executed and prints result of the condition, i want in new specified column from SELECT to display from another where clause, and so on, first somehow, i need to solve with this two queries, after that plan is to mix with about 10 queires. Thanks P.s one of the problems that, everything of results is displayed in column i_di1.naziv

```
SELECT bolnickiracun.id,
         bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza1, i_di1.naziv naziv_dijagnoza1
FROM     bolnickiracun
LEFT JOIN i_dijagnoze_marko i_di1 ON bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza1=i_di1.id
WHERE  bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza1!="" and i_di1.naziv is null
UNION ALL
SELECT bolnickiracun.id,
         bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza2, i_di2.naziv naziv_dijagnoza2
FROM     bolnickiracun
LEFT JOIN i_dijagnoze_marko i_di2 ON bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza2=i_di2.id
WHERE  bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza2!="" and i_di2.naziv is null
```

I want result to look like this:

```
id id_dijagnoza1   naziv_dijagnoza1   id_dijagnoza2   naziv_dijagnoza2
1     some data         null             
2     some data         null
3                                        some data         null
4                                        some data         null
```

point is to find naziv_dijagnoza1 or naziv_dijagnoza2 where is null, ie, where foreign key is showing not existing primary key, or someone import bad foreign key that not exist as a primary key.

Comment: sql-server ir mysql?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sry, my mistake, it is mysql

Comment: show `bolnickiracun`, `i_dijagnoze_marko` tables structure, few rows of data and expected result

Comment: @MariuszSzurgot i added expected result, sry but i can't show structure and rows of real data. i hope it's more clear now what is exptected result now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example for 3 `SELECT`'s (third one predicted by deduction based on pattern that can be seen) should help understand what you need to do with whole query for 10 `SELECT`'s. You need to fill with `NULL`'s every column after SELECT clause you dont'need in every `SELECT`.

```
SELECT bolnickiracun.id, bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza1, i_di1.naziv naziv_dijagnoza1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL -- and so on
FROM     bolnickiracun
LEFT JOIN i_dijagnoze_marko i_di1 ON bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza1=i_di1.id
WHERE  bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza1!="" and i_di1.naziv is null

UNION ALL

SELECT bolnickiracun.id, NULL, NULL, bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza2, i_di2.naziv naziv_dijagnoza2, NULL, NULL -- and so on
FROM     bolnickiracun
LEFT JOIN i_dijagnoze_marko i_di2 ON bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza2=i_di2.id
WHERE  bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza2!="" and i_di2.naziv is null

UNION ALL

SELECT bolnickiracun.id, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza3, i_di3.naziv naziv_dijagnoza3 -- and so on
FROM     bolnickiracun
LEFT JOIN i_dijagnoze_marko i_di3 ON bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza3=i_di3.id
WHERE  bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza3!="" and i_di3.naziv is null
```

The number of columns in every `SELECT` should be the same and as you can see, for 3 `SELECT`s it's 7 columns (2 per table joined x 3 `SELECT`s + 1 first column with ID). For 10 `SELECT`s it will be 21 columns in every `SELECT` clause (1 for id, 2 like in every table and the rest filled with `NULL`s). 
Not pretty solution but probably only with database structure like that.

So for 10 `SELECT`'s the frist and the last should look like this:

```
    SELECT bolnickiracun.id, bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza1, i_di1.naziv naziv_dijagnoza1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM     bolnickiracun
LEFT JOIN i_dijagnoze_marko i_di1 ON bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza1=i_di1.id
WHERE  bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza1!="" and i_di1.naziv is null

UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL

SELECT bolnickiracun.id, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza10, i_di10.naziv naziv_dijagnoza10
FROM     bolnickiracun
LEFT JOIN i_dijagnoze_marko i_di10 ON bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza10=i_di10.id
WHERE  bolnickiracun.id_dijagnoza10!="" and i_di10.naziv is null
```

Comment: thank u, this works fine, is it possible, to, in first select,  to put all names, and with other select to populate data ?

Comment: Rather not. First `SELECT` joins only `bolnickiracun` and `i_dijagnoze_marko` tables so if you try select dijagnoza3 - query will fail.
I tried find any other solution, for example somrthing with one select and many joins but i can't find any

Comment: I will solve names of columns with aliases, this will be a "physical work" because there is a lot of manual adjustments, but it's okay, because i get result that i  expected.